# Serializers vs views to retrieve object by foreign key field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'd like to allow users to perform POST request to create a blog post, and to use the `topic name` instead of the `topic id` as an option.

A minimal model might look as follows.

**models.py**

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

Now there are 2 possible approaches that I've considered:

> 1) Keep the views simple.

**views.py**

```
class PostList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topic_name  = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ('name', 'topic_name', 'created_on')
        read_only_fields = ('created_on',)

    def validate_topic_name(self, value):
        """Verify that the topic exists."""
        if not Topic.objects.filter(name=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Specified Topic Name does not exist!")
        else:
            return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a Post."""
        topic_name = validated_data.pop('topic_name', None)
        topic = Topic.objects.get(name=topic_name)  
        return Post.objects.create(topic=topic, **validated_data)
```

> 2) Keep the serializers simple.

**views.py**

```
class PostList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, name=serializer.data['topic_name'])  

        post = Post.objects.create(
                 name=serializer.data['name'],
                 topic=topic)

        return Response({'name': serializer.data['name'], 'description': serializer.data['topic_name']},
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topic_name  = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ('name', 'topic_name', 'created_on')
        read_only_fields = ('created_on',)
```

My question are:

- Where should I put the complexity? In the serializer on in the views?
- Is there a better way to proceed?

Comment: Are you sure the queryset of the complicated view is related to the Post? Should it not relate to the Topic if the serializer says its model is Topic? Or viceversa the serializer model should be Post instead of Topic

Comment: You're right, I've fixed it.

Comment: BTW i'd go for the complicated view and leave the serializer simple

Comment: I think this may be the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you want the client to use the topic id?

Comment: you might be right. This is simplified scenario and I've tried to create a minimal example. The goal is to allow users to use the name, guaranteed to be unique in addition to the id (avoiding to retrieve the id before the post request). However, the question focuses more on the design choice aspect: serializers vs view to manage the complexity of the api (e.g, checks, objects creations, etc)

Comment: @abc I see what you mean about the design choice. I think it all depends on the overall design of your application. If things like checks and object creations are inviolable across the application, it might be better to handle them at the model layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to put this complexity into your code at all, because this function is already provided by [`serializers.SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield), which allows you to refer to a related field using a string instead of an id.  Here's how it looks with your model:

**views.py**

```
class PostList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topic = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name',
                                         queryset=Topic.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```